# Can one use independent t-test to compare percentages?

Tags: t-test, proportion

For our research paper, our group plans to administer a sex inventory to students from two different schools which classifies them as sex-typed (meaning if you're male, you turn out masculine), sex-reversed (if you're male, you get classified as feminine), or androgynous.

Once they're classified, we plan to represent the number of people who are sex-typed, sex-reversed, and androgynous as percentages with respect to the sample size. Is it okay to use independent t-test to compare the percentages between the two schools?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare proportions, you could use a chi-square test. I don't know which program you are working with, but here are two sources on how to do it in R:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/comparison-of-two-proportions-parametric-z-test-and-non-parametric-chi-squared-methods/

http://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/BS/R/R6_CategoricalDataAnalysis/R6_CategoricalDataAnalysis6.html